# Can I open a file from specific offset1 to specific offset 2

Tags: gzip

In c++ enviroment, How can I open a file for the sake of merge it to a gzip file, I need to 
add part of the file to gzip file, can any body help? thank first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open it as usual, and then fseek() it.